# How to use glob command in sed command through tcl script

Tags: sed, tcl

I am having below file:

```
File path: ???
```

I want to replace this line with below:

```
File path: Path1/Path2/Path3/File.txt
```

I have tried the following through the tcl file. But it's not working:

```
sed -i "s|File path: ???|File path: glob $WORK_AREA/../../../*.txt|g" $file
```

Note: This path is having only 1 .txt file

How can i use the glob command in sed command through the .tcl file?

Answer (score 1):

Use several lines of code. It's so much easier.

```
set targetFile [lindex [glob $WORK_AREA/../../../*.txt] 0]
# You might also want to normalize the filename...
exec sed -i "s|File path: ???|File path: $targetFile|g" $file
```

You're *strongly* suggested to use `exec` explicitly in Tcl. You might also like this (which stops you from getting surprises in the directory path):

```
set targetFile [lindex [glob -directory $WORK_AREA/../../.. *.txt] 0]
```

And if `WORK_AREA` is an environment variable, you refer to those in Tcl using the `env` global array, like this: `$env(WORK_AREA)` or like this: `$::env(WORK_AREA)`.

I've *not* fixed the `???`. It *might* be replaceable with `.*` or maybe `.*txt` or any number of other regular expressions to match the text you want to remove. Without knowing your actual input data in depth, it's hard to be sure.

Comment: I'll often use `!` as the separator in sed expressions like you do, but pipe works too.

Comment: I have tried the above code with below : set targetFile [lindex [glob -directory $WORK_AREA/../../.. *.txt] 0]. It is throwing an error like set: Variable name must begin with a letter. Also, $WORK_AREA is only a path and normal variable.